# C# Polymorphism - Why & When

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I'm pretty much a junior level programmer and haven't yet came across the requirement of using Polymorphism in my experiences so far.

My basic understanding of polymorphism is creating something that requires the ability to handle various different types objects.

I'm just wondering if anyone out there can give some decent examples of when & why you would encounter this.

Sorry if my question appears dumb, I'm only a learner.

Comment: I can't think of any case where polymorphism is *required*. I can only think of cases where it is *desirable*. I am interested in learning about it as well.

Comment: So you have never used generics for example?

Comment: Have you ever used a `Stream`, for instance? You've probably been using polymorphism without being aware of it - which is kind of the point.

Comment: Yes I've used a stream, I'm looking at generics now.

Comment: I think you should first do googling for it

Comment: Any idea how many people are starting to learn a programming language each day? And what if they all dumped all their "what is xxxx" questions here?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I asked the question here as I use it as a trustworthy source. I try to anwser a lot of questions on here where I can, so I feel entitled to ask the question pal. Stackoverflow has a great community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polymorphism is useful any time you have a common contract but behavior varies from object to object. For example, take the ubiquitous "Job". You may have an interface like:

```
public interface IJob {
    void Execute(JobContext context);
}
```

and then implement various jobs that adhere to this contract, such as a DataPollingJob, a MaintenanceJob, EmailJob, BalanceJob, etc. whatever is running the jobs doesn't have to know what the implementation does or how it does it, but knows that it can call `Execute` with a context to have that job perform its function.

another common scenario in which polymorphism is helpful is in messaging. you may have many different types of messages, but they will all adhere to some basic contract that the messaging infrastructure understands.